# How to extract graph from microscope image?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I have a microscope image of actin filaments and I'd like to extract the geometry of the bright lines into a `Graph` object:

[image]

Here's what I have so far, using the above image as `img`:

```
s1 = MaxDetect@
   LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 8, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
s2 = MaxDetect[s1];
s3 = TopHatTransform[s2, 0.74];
s4 = DeleteSmallComponents[s2 - s3];
HighlightImage[img, s4]
```

[image]

But this misses lots of lines and the output isn't really a skeleton.

Here are a few more example images of the cytoskeleton to try this on:

```
example1 = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/defc77bb-8218-4660-9fb2-d851c1145cae"]
example2 = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b44045ec-f7ce-4db0-82bf-57e86d1967ac"]
```

Comment: Hm. Maybe you want to give `MorphologicalGraph[s1]` a try... But I am afraid, that is not exactly what you look for.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but the preprocessing is the tricky part

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

Comment: Not a MMA answer, but for preprocessing I'd check out [iLastik](http://ilastik.org/). After performing the segmentation with that, you could easily use mathematica for further processing.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for being late at the party,
I hope it is still relevant.
This is what I would do:

Setting your image as `img` I first equalize the brightness with `BrightnessEqualize`, then `Sharpen` the image, followed by some slight `Blur`, `Erosion` and a `RidgeFilter` that should bring us quite close to where you want to go

```
beq = BrightnessEqualize[img, {"Marginal", 2}]
```

[image]

```
sh = Sharpen[beq, 10]
bl = Blur[sh, 1];
er = Erosion[bl, 1];
rid = RidgeFilter[er, 2] // ImageAdjust;
```

[image]

Finally a `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` and a `Thinning` will give you what I hope is what you are looking for

```
lab = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[rid, 1]
```

[image]

```
Thinning[lab]
```

[image]

Optional:

If the First Local Adaptive Binarization step is giving you lines that are too thick, but the thinning backbone is too thin for what you need, you can perform a couple more Local Abdaptive Binarization followed by by blur, erosion, ridge filtering, sharpening... etc to get thinner lines

```
bin2 = ImageAdjust[lab~Blur~1~RidgeFilter~1] // Sharpen // Binarize
```

[image]

```
bin3 = ImageAdjust[bin2~Blur~2~Erosion~1~RidgeFilter~1] // Sharpen //
```

Binarize

[image]

Finally you can also create a Vectorized version of all your results using `ImageGraphics`

I Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm working on a related problem and I wasn't aware of either BrightnessEqualize or RidgeFilter. Very useful, +1! (I interfaced with SimpleITK through LibraryLink/LTemplate to get a local histogram equalization instead.)

Comment: This answer is much better than my comment masquerading as an answer. I agree with @Szabolcs that there are a few functions in here that are very useful -- and previously unknown, at least to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is too big for a comment, but I wouldn't consider it an answer, more of a suggestion or partial answer. I don't have any solid expertise in this area, but it seems to me like if you want to highlight these lines, you might want to do some edge detection. For example:

```
s1 = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[
 EdgeDetect[img, 2, 0.0275, Method -> "Sobel"],
 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
];
HighlightImage[img, s1]
```

[image: original image with messy red network overlay]

I'm not sure what it is we want to see, but to my eye this might be a step in the right direction at least. (?)

Also, I don't want to be "that guy," but are there higher resolution versions of these images? I might be wrong because this isn't exactly my wheelhouse, but I get the feeling it might be partially attributable to the fuzziness of the image, everything sort of glows and blends in, which might be less of an issue in a higher resolution image.